# Executing a periodic event for a table in mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have MYSQL workbench and have this table on a database that I want to clear-out every, say 5:00 pm in the afternoon, I don't have any knowledge when it comes to triggers so any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write an [event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events.html) which will get executed as per the specified schedule.

```
CREATE EVENT clearTable
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY
        STARTS '2014-10-16 17:00:00'
    COMMENT 'Description for the event'
    DO
       TRUNCATE tablename;
```